# Searching by selectbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with searching by selectbox. I found a very good plugin for searching ([QuickSearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch)), but it works only as an input type text. I need this to work as selectbox with options where they will have defined values ​​and the user will select from them.If anyone knows how to do this using either a quicksearch or something else I will be very grateful to him. Thank you for your help

Comment: Why don't you just pull the data off your selection and fire the QuickSearch's method?? I'm sure the plug-in must have a method which you can call and pass in your data as a parameter

Comment: Have you just tried doing `$('#options').quickSearch(...)`??

Comment: Hi Nupul, thanks for your reply. Yes that i am trying now, but so far I have no results :( Here is function https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch/blob/master/jquery.quicksearch.js but i dont know what to call of...

Comment: yes $('#options').quickSearch(...) i tried firstly. In selector is no problem i think

Answer (score 1):

Finally I sort it out. I just fired `change` event on selectbox to change value of input and also fired `keyup` event to make text input work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('input').quicksearch('#your-select option');
```